# Javascript JSON get index of value

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON format:

```
{ device: 'eth0',
      Rx: { bytes: '491539402315', packets: '278178082' },
      Tx: { bytes: '15113860013', packets: '67405143' } }
{ device: 'lo',
      Rx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' },
      Tx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' } }
```

I need to get index of device value so that i can later extract bytes and packets...i have in database value eth0 so i need to get index 0 (if i put lo i need to get index 1)

In javascript how can i do that?

Comment: Please note that what you have is not JSON, but a normal JavaScript Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that's an array you can simply iterate the array:

```js
var devices = [{ device: 'eth0',
      Rx: { bytes: '491539402315', packets: '278178082' },
      Tx: { bytes: '15113860013', packets: '67405143' } },
{ device: 'lo',
      Rx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' },
      Tx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' } }]
      
 function getIndex (name) {
   for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; ++i) {
    if (devices[i].device === name) {
      return i;
    }
   }
   return -1;
 }
 
console.log(getIndex("eth0"));
console.log(getIndex("lo"));
console.log(getIndex("missing device"));
```

Another slower approach, would be to use the `map` and `indexOf` functions:

```
var index = devices.map(c => c.device).indexOf(name);
```

Alternatively, `findIndex`, as Jaimec suggested, can be useful. If your are really concerned about the performance, you probably want to use the for loop version. Probably it doesn't matter that much in this context.

```
var index = devices.findIndex(c => c.device === name);
```

Comment: Youve just re-implemented `findIndex`

Comment: Thanks! This works awesome! I im trying today multiple times to get index using examples posted in this forum..but this works excellent..i try index for eth0 i get 0, then i try lo and get 1..excellent...thanks and big vote for you...

Comment: @John Cool! You can use `findIndex` as Jamiec suggested (thanks, I didn't know about that function, btw! :)), but the for loop implementation is always faster (if you're concerned about performance). In this case, any of them will work.

Answer (score 1):

this is a job for [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?v=example)!

```js
var devices = [{ device: 'eth0',
      Rx: { bytes: '491539402315', packets: '278178082' },
      Tx: { bytes: '15113860013', packets: '67405143' } },
{ device: 'lo',
      Rx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' },
      Tx: { bytes: '1653376107', packets: '6380792' } }]
      
      
var idx = devices.findIndex(function(e) { return e.device == "eth0"} );
console.log(idx);
```

Note that `findIndex` is not supported by IE. If you follow the link above there is a perfectly good polyfill to add support to unsupported browsers.